Is there any way to see up-to-date timetable information for SJ (not SJ NORD) trains in Norway?
I'm travelling with SJ to and from Oslo, and on SJ's own website the information about arrival times is only written as specified in the schedule for stops in Norway. When travelling with the EuroNight service to Denmark and Germany I was able to see this information through Banedanmark and Deutsche Bahn, but with Norway I haven't been able to find any equivalent. There is https://www.vy.no/trafikk-og-ruter/rutetider, but it only includes Vy trains. It says to check Go-Ahead and SJ NORD's websides for information about their trains, but nothing about SJ itself.
Is there anywhere I can see up-to-date departure and arrival information about SJ trains in Norway?

I read it as you are looking for real-time information and not really a timetable

@Anders Yeah, do you have any suggestions for better phrasing?

The app called "Nå" shows real-time info in Norway for the SJ trains between Oslo and Stockholm. https://www.banenor.no/en/traffic-and-travel/the-travel-app-na/


SJ NORD is a subsidiary for SJ that runs trains fully in Norway.
If you are not looking for trains that are fully in Norway (like ones between it and Sweden), you need to go to the Swedish SJ website as they are ran by the main company.
Going to Traffic Info, and for example entering Oslo as the station, gives me the real time info of the Oslo to Stockholm train

SJ's website only gives real-time information about the part of the trip that happens in Sweden, as noted in the original question. It's not translated for some reason but it say "tid enl. tidtabell" which means "time according to timetable" for the stations in Norway. Or in other words, not real-time information.
